# Find Object of Object MongoDB not returning any values

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have this data structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("582ecaa97be792282ca31bc4"),
"hero" : {
    "5001" : {
        "id" : 5001
        "name" : "Rogue"
             }
    "5002" : {
        "id" : 5002
        "name" : "Mage"
             }
    "5003" : {
        "id" : 5002
        "name" : "Paladin"
             }
         }
}
```

I have the query.

```
db.getCollection('hero').find({"Hero":{"5001":{"id" : 5001}}})
```

It returns 0 results.
I could store the Heros separately, but I would like to know how to do this query first. What I would like to get out of this is all data under 5001 if I query with 5001 and so forth.

Thanks!

Edit: I found the answer by using dot notation, I already tried dot notation but i got it a bit wrong when trying it, I thought it was only for arrays. Here is what you would do if anyone else is looking.

```
db.Runes.find({ "hero.5001.id": 5001 },{"hero.5001":1})
```

Comment: I've You need to change your document structure and make `hero` an array of subdocuments.

Comment: Sure I will also do that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, All the fields are case sensitive so you cannot query a "hero" field with "Hero".

second if you are querying nested documents you should use the "dot notation"

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

so the proper way to your that document will be.

```
db.getCollection('hero').find({"hero.5001.id" : 5001})
```

it will return the entire document. So entire hero object with 5002 and 5003 key will also return as they belong to the same document. You can use projection to project only the required fields.
which can be done as below

```
db.getCollection('hero').find({"hero.5001.id": 5001},{"hero.5001" : 1})
```

Here are more information about Mongodb query and projection operators
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
db.getCollection('hero').find({"hero.5001.id" : 5001})
```